# How to transform German umlauts when creating slugs?

Tags: localization, slug

First of all, I want to thank you for creating Craft. It's really one of the best content management systems I have ever worked with.

I encountered an issue while working on a multilingual site: German Umlauts are not automatically transliterated (**Ä -> Ae**) for slugs. In other parts of Craft (e.g. field handles) Umlauts *are* transliterated automatically.

Personally, I would prefer if this behavior could be controlled by a config variable (e.g. `slugExpandUmlauts`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try enabling the config setting [`limitAutoSlugsToAscii`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#limitAutoSlugsToAscii), that should do what you want.

Comment: This works great when entering titles in the frontend, but how can I enable it on the backend? (I want to import contents from a legacy CMS via a plugin.)

Comment: How are you doing the import?

Comment: Based on [craftimport](https://github.com/clearbold/craftimport) I created a custom input plugin where I create and save the entries.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any such option serverside, but maybe you can just recreate the functionality. Check line 9311 in craft.js, the function Craft.SlugGenerator. It does basic replaces, and you can probably convert the rules easily, copying the existing regex.

Comment: Thank you, Fred. It's actually pretty straightforward. Craft uses a simple character map (craft.js - line 25) - I didn't know that.

Answer (score -1):

If it´s a one-time operation, maybe you could just import everything and search/replace in MySQL?